# read django data from model and write it using xlsxwriter

Tags: django, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I need to extract all the data from a model(called Aged) I have and trigger a function to export it as a .xls file. I have found xlsxWriter not sure if I'm in the right path, is there a way I can just call my full model and write it into a file?

This is what I got on my views.py:

```
def writetoexcel(Reportdata):
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Reporte3a4.xlsx', 
                                   {'constant_memory': True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

    worksheet.write('A1', 'Priority', bold)
    worksheet.write('B1', 'PO Number', bold)

    Reporte = Reporte3a5.objects.all()

    row = 1
    col = 0

    for data in Reporte:
        worksheet.write(row, col, data.secondary_priority)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, data.po_number)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 2, data.ctb_status)

    workbook.close()
    xlsx_Data = output.getvalue()
    return  xlsx_Data
```

Comment: Just a note that the code overwrites the data in the `A1` and `B1` cells in the loop when `row = 0`. It should probably start from `row = 1`.

Comment: Oh yeah I just noticed that yesterday at the afternoon, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this answer to my own question, this is just other model I used:

```
def xlsx(request):
    # Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
    output = io.BytesIO()
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output, {'in_memory': True})
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Reporte3a5')
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
    # Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
    reporte = Reporte3a5.objects.all() #my model

    # Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
    row = 1
    col = 0

    # Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
    for linea in reporte:
        worksheet.write(row, col, linea.df_status)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, linea.aged)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 2, linea.ship_set)
        row += 1

    # Write the title for every column in bold
    worksheet.write('A1', 'Priority', bold)
    worksheet.write('B1', 'Code', bold)

    workbook.close()

    output.seek(0)
    response = HttpResponse(output.read(), content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=Reporte3a5.xlsx"

    return response
```

With this you will get the file automatically downloaded in the same page.